# Issue with firstOrCreate when creating a row in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table that is empty at the start of the script (this will later be applied to an existing table with thousands of rows, but the new test table I created to test the script on is obviously empty). I'm trying to use `firstOrCreate` but it's not inserting the rows as expected. Here's the object:

```
Bar::firstOrCreate([
    'file_id' => $xmlFile->file_id, // 1999
], [
    'file_id'             => $xmlFile->file_id,
    'article_id'          => $article->article_id,
    'public_supp_file_id' => null,
    'uploader_id'         => null,
    'title'               => 'dafdsfsdfdsfjkdsfskd',
    'creator'             => null,
    'subject'             => null,
    'type'                => 'Type',
    'type_id'             => 11,
    'type_other'          => null,
    'description'         => null,
    'publisher'           => null,
    'sponsor'             => null,
    'date_created'        => $xmlFile->date_uploaded,
    'source'              => null,
    'language'            => null,
    'show_reviewers'      => 1,
    'date_submitted'      => $xmlFile->date_uploaded,
    'seq'                 => $sequence,
    'app_num'             => $sequence,
    'fig_num'             => 0,
    'copyright'           => null,
    'url'                 => null,
    'license_id'          => null,
    'other'               => null,
]);

dd('reached'); // reached
```

Not sure what's happening, no rows are being inserted. According to the docs, if no rows with a `file_id` of `1999` is found, my code suggests the script should create a row with that `file_id` and the rest of those values. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't need the `file_id` in both arrays. Just the first one is okay, as if it won't find it it will still persist it from the first one. I noticed you just edited `firstOrNew` to `firstOrCreate` have you tried with both? Because with `firstOrNew` you are missing a call to the `save` method.

Comment: Im using firstOrCreate, I was testing with other methods, but firstOrCreate is the what's not working for me. It's just adding a row for each iteration with the correct file_id and 0 for the article_id and null for everything else (when none of the values, unless explicitly indicated, are null)

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing `protected $guarded = [];` in the model definition. I had only protected `protected $fillable = ['file_id'];`